# Мне экспортировать полностью картинку или же как-то её "обрезать"

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Да, я задавала подобный вопрос, но не получила того решения которое мне было нужно. Мой вопрос заключается в том, что я не понимаю как именно мне сделать картинку в карточке.

1. Мне её обрезать до той ширины и высоты как она помещается в карточку.
2. Либо мне её экспортировать в начальном виде, но тогда как её разместить.
   Я ещё новичок, поэтому напишите как было бы сделать правильнее и лучше в проекте.

---

Вот сама каточка, но размер у картинки намного больше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и сама картинка в карточке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще один пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Импортируете картинку через тег img:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXEmp.png"/>
```

Задаете ей класс, в файле стилей указываете размер картинки.

Если нужно не уменьшить, а обрезать, указываете в стилях изображения

```
object-fit: none;
```

Если нужно уменьшить, но сохранить пропорции:

```
object-fit: contain;
```

> Свойство object-fit определяет, каким образом содержимое замещаемых элементов будет подогнано к краям контейнера тега в случае, когда для элемента заданы ширина и высота, отличные от его собственных размеров.

> Свойство object-fit масштабирует, обрезает или растягивает содержимое замещаемых элементов.

> **contain**   - Содержимое элемента масштабируется, выравниваясь по центру с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы полностью поместиться внутри контейнера.

А по хорошему давайте пример вашего кода, который есть, что бы людям было легче разобраться и дать Вам корректный ответ.

Comment: Если нужно, что бы лишнее содержимое картинки, которые выходит за границу родительского блока скрывалось, задайте самой карточке свойство overflow: hidden;